# Calling a service twice in a function?

Tags: linux, bash, service

I've written a service for some basic monitoring and error reporting for my users to use to check on functions of some servers. The problem I have is that I have a lengthy function to make a report to output to a text file and I want to have another option to email this text file across to me. When I try to call the function in the mail section of the service it doesn't know what that function is.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
report)
function report (){

...
commands
...
}
report > text.txt
;;
mail)
report > test.txt
mail -s "Hell" user@example.com < test.txt
```

Comment: What syntax is this `report)`?

Comment: The report function is part of a script that gets copied to /etc/init.d/ to run as a service so case "$1" in then different functions. The report itself is just doing greps, awks and some cat's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the `report()` function outside of the `report)` case (put it up above the `case` keyword).